# Using Python to communicate to Raspberry Pi via serial

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, pyserial

Hello stackoverflow community, I have been working on a personal project and I need some assistance.  I have a RaspberryPi that I am using to store messages from a PC via a usb-to-serial connection.  Currently, I can use Putty to connect to the RPi using the COM port 3 (asks for a user id/password) and gives me a shell (ttyAMA0).  My end goal is to write a piece of code in python that listens for communication from the PC (also in Python) such that when I type a message (i.e. "hello world"), it will send it to the RPi on COM3 and the RPi will receive it and save it to file.

My methodology could be wrong (obviously sinceit is not working) but this is what I have so far:

**This Python Script is running on RPi (I am logged in via network Connection (SSH)) and it is listening for a message from PC via ttyAMA0**

```
import serial
import time

def readlineCR(port):
        rv = ""
        while True:
                ch = port.read()
                rv += ch
                if ch=="\r' or ch=='';
                        return rv

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=115200, timeout = 3.0)

while True:
        rcv = readlineCR(port)
        print 'message received: ' + repr(rcv)
```

**This Python script is running on PC**

```
import serial

ser = 0

def init_serial():
     COMNUM = 3          
     global see          
     ser = serial.Serial()
     ser.baudrate = 115200
     ser.port = COMNUM - 1   #this makes it COM3
     ser.timeout = 10
     ser.open()          

     if ser.isOpen():
          print 'Open: ' + ser.portstr

init_serial()
ser.write(‘root’ + '\n')
ser.write(‘<PASWORD HERE>’ + '\n')

while True:
    msg = raw_input(“message: \r\n“)
    ser.write(msg)
    print ‘sent: ‘+ msg +’\r\n’
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you receive any `Traceback error` message or you don't receive anything from the `serial` port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you have to comment out the line that tells raspi to use ttyAMA0.
See, by default a terminal is bound to ttyAMA0, so you cannot use it for anything else. I mean, even if you do 'talk' to it programatically, you will be 'speaking' with OS, not with your Python process.
Somewhere at the bottom of "/etc/inittab" you'll see the line in question.
When you comment it out, and reboot, you will be able to use it as normal COM port with pyserial (from both ends). Although I would be careful in your place, because the normal RS232 by specification gives out 10V and output pin on raspi does 3.5V if I am not gravely mistaken. It may work fine or it may be a disaster after some time you leave it on or it simply won't work with longer cable.
You would need some IC such as maxcom or something to regulate the voltage for you. Or, just use two USB2Serial converters, one on PC and another on raspi and you need to do nothing special to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

```
init_serial()
ser.write('root')
ser.write('<PASSWORD HERE>')
```

If I'm not mistaken (can't test it here), you are not sending `\n` at the end of root and the password (`ser.write()` does not add them as `print()` does), so you are not logging in correctly.

By the way, it would not hurt making the script wait for each prompt - if you start your program before the RPi, the login will be lost.

EDIT: If that does not work, try running either [a serial line sniffer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/slsnif) or run Wireshark and check the USB protocol (more difficult) That way you can monitor what is exactly happening.

Comment: Added \n to both user id and password.  I think my methodology is incorrect.

Comment: Added another suggestion to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I had to comment out any references to ttyAMA0 in the cmdline.txt file, so that I wouldn't be prompted for a serial console. No need to try and pass credentials.

reference:
http://elinux.org/Serial_port_programming